# Constant Buzzing on Multiple Microphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

I have tried two separate mics (USB and headphone jack) and both always have an annoying background noise. I tried one of them in another computer (Mac) and it was fine.

Upon doing research I found the microphone properties enhancements tab, but that is not showing on my computer, even after updating to the latest Realtek driver.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: "Buzzing": 50 or 60 Hz hum from mains leakage? Your description is vague, but seems like a *hardware* issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Even if its all usb plugins and headphone jacks doing the same thing? I don't know how to explain the hum